# Jetty 9 FontAwesome Empty Icons

Tags: java, css, jetty, mime-types, font-awesome

I am hosting my Java webapp with Jetty 9, and I'd like to host the fontawesome icons myself. However I don't see the icons properly (they're square. If I link from the CDN, it works fine

This link works

```
  <%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">--%>
```

This doesn't

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

I've tried adding the following to my web.xml

```
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-opentype</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-truetype</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff2</extension>
    <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

All I get from IE is the following

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. File:
OpenSans-Light.ttf
```

and Chrome

```
Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/theme-triton/resources/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/theme-triton/resources/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/theme-triton/resources/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/theme-triton/resources/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/theme-triton/resources/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/theme-triton/resources/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/font-awesome-4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/font-awesome-4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0
index.jsp:1 Failed to decode downloaded font:
localhost:8080/resources/font-awesome-4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0
```

Response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-font-truetype
Last-Modified: Sun, 31 May 2015 17:30:12 GMT 
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 359350
Server: Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)
```

Request Header

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:localhost:8080/wro/test.css
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2418.0 Safari/537.36
```

Can anyone tell me what/where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Can u put a link where its hosted. Have you checked in Element Inspector that the file is linked correctly as you want it? EDIT: Ok, from your log, I think you have ensured correct linking. Can you still check and confirm once that the css file referred by you in html opens fine on click in Source Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't specify I was using maven to build my project. I just have to specify what file extensions that maven should not filter, if not maven will corrupt the file. It is similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31475762/4959062

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try delete '?v=4.3.0' suffix in @font-face { } block local's css.