# How do I load custom font in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, angular6

I am currently working in angular 6. I wanted to load my fonts in style.css, but it is not working. My code is shown below. Could someone suggest how I may reproduce this issue?

Note: I used the same syntax which was working in angular 5. What is wrong with it?

style.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Expert Sans';
  src: url('assets/fonts/ExpertSans-Regular.ttf');
}


body {
  font-family: 'Expert Sans' !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please add format('opentype') in your code

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Expert Sans';
  src: url('assets/fonts/ExpertSans-Regular.ttf') format("opentype");
}
```

For More detail information Please follow this link 
[How to import a new font into a project - Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878988/how-to-import-a-new-font-into-a-project-angular-5)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying body element that is why it did not affect. Finally i added a *(star). it worked for me. please try it.

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: Expert Sans;
      src: url('assets/fonts/ExpertSans-Regular.ttf');
    }
    
    * {
      font-family: Expert Sans !important;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, you can perfectly make self-answered questions, though it seems you are using 2 different accounts. I have a feeling that will be frowned upon by moderators, not completely sure though.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thank you.