# Import custom font to Angular/CSS

Tags: css, angular, fonts, bootstrap-4

Somehow the font I chose won't display, even tho I did what was mentioned in similar threads.

I use Angular and I'm currently trying to import a custom font via @font-face.

One of my approaches so far:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Hearth Stone;
  src: url(/src/assets/fonts/HearthStone.otf) format("opentype");
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 10px 70px 10px 70px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Hearth Stone;
}
```

Further information:

- Angular 7
- Latest Bootstrap Version
- CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a new font into a project - Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878988/how-to-import-a-new-font-into-a-project-angular-5)

Comment: @JohanRin Already have tried the same thing, doesn't work for me

Comment: There should be no "src" in the path