# How to use local font family in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, fonts, font-family

I have some custom fonts in my /assets/font folder , let's say it is "ITC Charter Com Black" and I got four kind of files :`.eot` `.svg` `.tff` `.woff`.

and how can I use these font in my project?
I tired:`font-family: 'ITC Charter Com Black';`

it is not work.

Comment: @David more like `assets`

Comment: David or edit it, I'll remove mine :)

Comment: You need to make sure that you add these files in the `assets` section of the `angular.json` file, then you can just reference them in css with `@font-face`, as suggested in the answer below and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878988/how-to-import-a-new-font-into-a-project-angular-5

Answer (score 13):

**Setup before using the Custom Font**

**Step 1:** In the folder `src/assets` create a new folder `fonts` so the new path looks like `src/assets/fonts`.

**Step 2:** Place your custom font .ttf file inside this `src/assets/fonts` so the new path looks like `src/assets/fonts/custom_font.ttf`.

**Step 3:** Now in the folder `fonts` create a new .css file such as `font-file.css` so now the path looks like `src/assets/fonts/font-file.css`. Inside this file write this,

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "my_custom_font";
  src: url("./custom_font.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

After three steps this is how your directory structure should look like,

```
src -
     |
      - ...   //other folders
     | 
      - assets // assets folder
              |
               -fonts // fonts folder
                     |
                      -font-file.css //.css file
                     |
                      -custom_font.ttf //.ttf file
```

**Step 4:** Go to your `angular.json` file and under the very first `options:{}` attribute you will have `styles:[]`. In this paste the full path to your `font-files.css` such as

```
"options": {
            ...,
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/fonts/font-file.css" //the path to your font-file.css which we defined earlier in step3
            ]

          }
```

**Using Custom Font**

Now you can easily use the newly added custom font such as,

```
body {
    ...
    font-family: 'my_custom_font', 'arial', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add font-family in style.css like this -

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'appfont';
  src: url('/fonts/TitilliumWeb-Regular.ttf');
}

body {
  font-family: 'appfont', sans-serif;
}
```